# Кеширование изменяемых изображений

Tags: php, yii2, yii, кэширование

Как в `yii` можно кешировать изображения?
 Сейчас у меня все изображения берутся прямо из папки `uploads`, они отлично кешируются средствами `nginx`. Но есть одна проблема, - если в эту папку положить файл, допустим с именем `demo.jpg`, затем заставить браузер закешировать его, и после заменить файл на другой файл с тем же именем, то браузер будет отдавать первоначальный(закешированый) файл.
Понятно что нужно как-то изменять ссылку на изображение, когда файл был заменен (Например так: http://site.ru/uploads/demo.jpg?v2), но как это сделать в `yii2`?

Comment: также как и в любом фреймворке, например AssetManager использует функцию [filemtime](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.filemtime.php), с помощью которой добавляет к ссылке на файл время его последнего изменения в unixTimeStamp, код: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/AssetManager.php#L322

Answer (score 1):

Изменять название картинки это само по себе "костыль". У Вас в кэше картинка с названием http://site.ru/uploads/demo.jpg так и останется + добавится новая картинка http://site.ru/uploads/demo.jpg?v2 и так далее.

Главная задача - это добиться инвалидации кэша после изменения ресурса (заголовки `Last-Modified` `Etag`).

С yii особо не знаком, но думаю стоит копать в сторону [HTTP Caching](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-http.html)

С другой стороны, вы можете обойтись настройкой nginx для статических файлов, как описано в этой [статье](https://blog.theodo.fr/2016/06/improve-the-performance-of-your-webapp-configure-nginx-to-cache/).

Суть в том, что нужно установить такие настройки как `add_header Cache-Control must-revalidate;`
и добавить  `etag on`;

Обратите внимание на замечания:

> Вы не должны добавлять параметр `Last-Modified`, так как nginx автоматически устанавливает его последней датой изменения ресурса в файловой системе

---

*Как работает http-cache простым языком можно прочитать [тут](http://html5.by/blog/cache/).*
Так же рекомендую прочитать книгу [Web-протоколы](https://www.twirpx.com/file/99839/)